# Query that displays rows in a range of date with day, month and year

Tags: mysql

I have the following columns in my table Log:

year, month, day, info

I need a query that selects the rows in a range of date determined by the user. The user will select the initial day, month and year and also the final day, month and year. At the moment, my query is:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(LPAD(`day`,2, 0),'/',LPAD(`month`,2, 0),'/',`year`) AS data,
    info
FROM
    Log
WHERE
    (year > :initial_year OR (year = :initial_year AND month >= :initial_moth AND day >= :initial_day))
    AND (year < :final_year OR (year = :final_year AND month <= :final_month AND day <= :final_day))
GROUP BY
    year, month, day
ORDER BY
    year DESC, month DESC, day DESC
```

But this query doesn't display any results, even that they are in the database! What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you had used _one_ `date` field, instead of splitting this up into three separate fields …

Comment: You are right, but I can't modify the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is wrong:

```
WHERE (
        year > :initial_year OR (
          year = :initial_year AND month >= :initial_moth AND day >= :initial_day
        )
      )
```

Will exclude any dates in your initial year where the day portion is greater than the initial day portion. e.g. `yyyy-01-31` as the initial day will exclude all results for `yyyy` where the day portion is not 31.

Similar problems exist with the final date.

As suggested in the comments, use one `DATE` field in your database and do the other fiddling in your application code; it will save a lot of drama.

If you can't change the database, find and berate the person who designed it until they change it. If you can't do that then:

```
WHERE (year>:initial_year OR (year=:initial_year AND (month>:initial_month OR (month=:initial_month AND day>=:initial_day))))
```

and similar for the final date

Answer (score 0):

What about:

select
concat(year,month,day) as thedate, info
from
log
where
thedate >= :startdate and thedate <= :enddate
order by
thedate desc;

Comment: Apart from the hideous formatting; you can't use a column alias in the `WHERE` clause.